# Ready to use dialog node's condition list of Watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm using Watson conversation and could anyone give me a list of ready to use dialog node's condition, like condition "conversation_start" to display the first response and condition "Anything else" to provide a default response.

Answer (score 0):

See this link for the list of conditions, the built-in global variables written in the Spring Expression (SpEL) language:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/expression-language.html

Answer (score 0):

The following special conditions are available:

welcome: This condition is evaluated as true during the first dialog turn (when the conversation starts), only if the initial request from the application does not contain any user input. It is evaluated as false in all subsequent dialog turns. Typically, a node with this condition is used to greet the user, for example, to display a message such as "Welcome to our Pizza ordering app."

conversation_start: Like welcome, this condition is evaluated as true during the first dialog turn, but unlike welcome, it is true whether or not the initial request from the application contains user input. You can use a node with the welcome condition, a node with the conversation_start condition, or both, depending on the design of your application. A node with the conversation_start condition can be used to initialize context variables or perform other tasks at the beginning of the dialog.

anything_else: You can use this condition at the end of a dialog, to be processed when the user input does not match any other dialog nodes.

irrelevant: This condition will evaluate to true if the user’s input is determined to be irrelevant by the Conversation service.

true: This condition is always evaluated to true. You can use it at the end of a list of nodes or responses to catch any responses that did not match any of the previous conditions.

false: This condition is always evaluated to false. You might use this at the top of a branch that is under development, to prevent it from being used, or as the condition for a node that provides a common function and is used only as the target of a Jump to action.